# Perfcounter ASP.NET Apps v4.0.30319/Requests Executing never goes down

Tags: performance, iis, perfmon

We have ASP.NET application (with both MVC 5 and WebAPI controllers) running on Windows Server 2016 (IIS 10). Some time ago we faced performance degradation and during the analysis found out that Perfcounter for ASP.NET Apps v4.0.30319/Requests Executing never goes down. It just raises during the day and app pool recycle is the only way to make it zero. It can raise up to several thousands which seems to me totally incorrect and abnormal. I assume this is definitely related to our performance issues. However, I haven't managed to find any explanations to it.

Any thoughts on this matter are highly appreciated.

[Perfcounters charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOm8p.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I've found the reason of raising Requests Executing counter. In our case that was happening while requesting a particular action where we use pretty tricky approach for rendering Razor view into a string.

We used method that is described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23504283/4177362. So we were creating new `HttpContext` per `FakeController`. And that was the issue - after it is changed to current context the counter started to work properly.